# I want to split string and passed as complex json string to form custom field using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have string values like below:

```
demo1 = "A:3 ; B:2"

demo2 = "A:3 ; Z:1 ; T:4"

main = "thisDemoIsNew"
```

I want to split values from `main` string using above demo1 and demo2.

For example - for demo1 I will generate new string like below

```
NewString = "A:thi ; B:sD"
```

I want to do it using logic app.

demo1 shows A:3 and B:2 here 3 and 2 is length which we will take from `main` string variable.

For example, for demo2 I will generate new string like below
NewString = "A:thi ; Z:s ; T:Demo"

I want to do it using logic app.

demo2 shows A:3 ; Z:1 ; T:4  here 3 ,1 and 4 is length which we will take from `main` string variable.

How to achieve this in logic app i can take new variables to split but what should be split expression based on length of demo1 and demo2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels like this is an overly complex way of doing it but, I go thru a few conversions to make it first into JSON and then append to a variable in a few for each loops with `concurrency set to enabled` and `degree of parallelism set to 1`.

I have included all expressions and splits in comments for each action.

Now if you want to make this for both Demo1 and Demo2 in one go you need to wrap my solution to handle arrays.

Edit: I realize that I created an array as a result but you could easily when you have gotten this far instead append all of it to a string.
[image: Result]

[image: Variables]
[image: Create Json Array]
[image: Create Array]

Code connection info, it's with both a onedrive and a storage blob, currently connected to a storage blob instead and final output to excel table:

`{
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azureblob": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/resourceGroups/StackOverFlow/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                "connectionName": "azureblob",
                "id": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/azureblob"
            },
            "excelonlinebusiness": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/resourceGroups/StackOverFlow/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/excelonlinebusiness",
                "connectionName": "excelonlinebusiness",
                "id": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/excelonlinebusiness"
            },
            "onedriveforbusiness": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/resourceGroups/StackOverFlow/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/onedriveforbusiness",
                "connectionName": "onedriveforbusiness",
                "id": "/subscriptions/[GUID]/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/onedriveforbusiness"
            }
        }
    },
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Get_blob_content')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each_row": {
                "actions": {
                    "Add_a_row_into_a_table": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "Hours": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['PackageServiceId']",
                                "Id": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['ActiveUsers']",
                                "Name": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['AgreementID']"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['excelonlinebusiness']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/codeless/v1.2/drives/@{encodeURIComponent('[Some long hash]')}/items/@{encodeURIComponent('[Some long hash]')}/workbook/tables/@{encodeURIComponent('{[GUID]}')}/rows",
                            "queries": {
                                "source": "me"
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "[Some long hash]": "/LOL/Bok1.xlsx"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "clear_tempArray_for_next_row": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    },
                    "Clear_data_of_special_characters": {
                        "description": "replace(replace(replace(item(),'[',''),']',''),'\"','')",
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "data",
                            "value": "@{replace(replace(replace(item(),'[',''),']',''),'\"','')}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "For_each_item_on_row": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_tempArray": {
                                "description": "Create array to hold values before compose and json",
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "tempArray",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each_item_on_row')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "description": "split(variables('data'),',')",
                        "foreach": "@split(variables('data'),',')",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Clear_data_of_special_characters": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    },
                    "Parse_JSON": {
                        "description": "Parse into json object",
                        "inputs": {
                            "content": "@variables('data')",
                            "schema": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "ActiveUsers": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "AgreementID": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "PackageServiceId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_data_to_json_formated_string": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ParseJson"
                    },
                    "Set_data_to_json_formated_string": {
                        "description": "Create json string using tempArray: variables('tempArray')?[0] throu variables('tempArray')?[2]",
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "data",
                            "value": "{\n\"AgreementID\":\"@{variables('tempArray')?[0]}\",\n\"PackageServiceId\":\"@{variables('tempArray')?[1]}\",\n\"ActiveUsers\":\"@{variables('tempArray')?[2]}\"\n}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "For_each_item_on_row": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    },
                    "clear_tempArray_for_next_row": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "tempArray",
                            "value": "@null"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Parse_JSON": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "description": "split on newline in csv doc. @split(body('Get_file_content'),'\\r\\n')",
                "foreach": "@split(outputs('Compose'),'\r\n')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_'data'_string": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_blob_content": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[Some long hash]'))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "[Some long hash]": "/stackoverflow/blob.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_file_content": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_file_content": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['onedriveforbusiness']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[Some long hash]'))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "[Some long hash].[Some long hash]": "/LOL/Bok1.csv",
                    "[Some long hash].[Some long hash]": "/LOL/Bok1.xlsx",
                    "[Some long hash].[Some long hash]": "/LOL/ReadStuff.csv"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_'data'_string": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "data",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_'tempArray'_array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_'tempArray'_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "tempArray",
                            "type": "Array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: I'm getting all duplicate value into Parse json output :( I'm using for each for my input json at very starting ... can you paste a full logic app code here?

Comment: @Neo Updated, without connection info. I have changed the logic app slightly to use a storage blob as the source and excel as a destination.